# R: Win32 error mentioned in LoadLibrary failure while dynamically loading 64-bit DLL

Tags: r, gcc, dll, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I have a 64-bit architecture laptop with Windows 8.1 64-bit OS.

I compile foo.c that has a simple function
to print the passed string, with gcc :

```
D:\>\r64\r-3.3.0\bin\r --arch 64 CMD SHLIB foo.c
gcc -m64 -I"D:/r64/r-3.3.0/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"D:/R64/R-    3.3.0/extsoft/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c foo.c -o foo.o

gcc -m64 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o foo.dll tmp.def foo.o -LD:/R64/R-3.3.0/extsoft/lib/x64 -LD:/R64/R-3.3.0/extsoft/lib -LD:/r64/r-3.3.0/bin/x64 -lR
```

And then I dynamically load that, in R :

```
dyn.load("foo.o")
```

And I get the following error:

> Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
>     unable to load shared object 'D:/R/classification/InC/foo.o':
>     LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Why is Win32 mentioned in the error when I compiled the code in 64-bit 
architecture?

Comment: Are you 100% running a 64 b it version of R (see `sessionInfo()`)?

Comment: Looks like it....Here's the sessionInfo () output:

> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.2

Comment: R_ARCH also shows /x64

Comment: Do not know much about R. But I think it should be dyn.load("foo.dll").